# EventKit: reminders dueDateComponents vs Alarm

Tags: objective-c, ios, eventkit

I want to create a reminder from my app, so I've created a reminder (EKReminder) and set up an alarm:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 100000;
NSDate *alarmDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeInterval];
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:alarmDate];
[reminder setAlarms:@[alarm]];
```

but I see there is also a dueDateComponents property on EKReminder. What is the difference between setting an alarm and the dueDateComponents?

Also there there is a method to create an alarm: `alarmWithRelativeOffset:(NSTimeInterval)offset` but the docs say the offset argument can be negative, how is it possible to have an alarm in the past?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a `EKReminder` item is kind of like a task on a todo list with an optional start date and due date, the `dueDateComponents` property allows you to specify when a task should be completed. It'll allow you to show overdue items for example. This is informational and is separate from an alarm.

Setting an alarm on a reminder will cause the Reminders app to notify the user when the alarm goes off.

I guess this is slightly confusing because the Reminders app doesn't appear to let you set a  due date, only an alarm date. However on this blog post it shows how you used to be able to set a due date but no reminder date on icloud.com:  http://blog.truthdialogue.com/2012/07/setting-due-dates-in-the-os-x-mountain-lion-reminders-app.html. It looks as if Apple have simplified the apps since the API was developed.

The offset for `alarmWithRelativeOffset:` is from the start date/time of an event. So you can set an alarm to go off x minutes before an event for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
let alarmist : EKAlarm = EKAlarm()
alarmist.relativeOffset = -0
reminder.addAlarm(alarmist)
NSLog("reminder has alarm ->" + reminder.hasAlarms.description)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 EKAlarm *reminder = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-00];
        [event addAlarm:reminder];
```